# SQL not updating table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got some code for an inventory system i've been working on for my project. everything in the code works fine, unless you try to update an item with the IID of '1' (Or at least that was i'm assuming the problem is)

```
    function useItem($uid, $iid)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE player_inv SET amount = amount - 1 WHERE uid = :uid AND iid = :iid";
    $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $que->bindParam('uid', $uid);
    $que->bindParam('iid', $iid);
    try{
    $que->execute();
        if($que)
        {
        echo "True";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "Wut?";    
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){echo $e->getMessage();}
}
function ReapWhatYouSow($iid, $uid)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE users join store on users.uid = :uid  and iid = :iid SET health = store.type_value + health;";
    $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $que->bindParam('uid', $_SESSION['uid']);
    $que->bindParam('iid', $iid);
    try{
        $que->execute();
        if($que)
        {
            $this->useItem($iid, $uid);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "wut?";
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){ echo $e->getMessage(); }
}
```

Please ignore the echo's... I really suck at error reporting so the 'wut' and 'true' are my way of checking to see if something is functioning correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by _remove_? Neither of your shown functions remove anything, though one of them decreases inventory. What is going wrong with it? What does it do _instead_ of what you expect it to do?

Comment: Yah, I phrased that wrong, should've said "update" the table. It doesn't do anything, it basically ignores the item if it's ID number is '1'.

Comment: I guess you should either get an exception, or PDO can give you an error message in another way. Have you tried to read it? Something like this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php

Comment: There is no error, the code is working it just wont update the row... which i realize means it's not working. but it's not throwing me an error anywhere i can see.

Comment: Check [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) Examine the data in your table - perhaps you don't actually _have_ the row you are trying to update. That isn't an error condition, just an unmatched `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I'm a morron. Thank you guys for the help! It was a variable issue, I switched the UID with the IID. so the query was deleting every item that had the same ID# as the users ID#

Comment: Easy to do, hard to find when it stares at you

Comment: That's an understatement. The funny thing is, that was the first thing i thought of, and somehow I'm like "nahhh that can't be it! everything else is working!"

Answer (score 0):

First spontanius reaction... Is the function `ReapWhatYouSow($iid, $uid)` even called? I guess it is but then this row does not make sense:

```
$que->bindParam('uid', $_SESSION['uid']); //No sense to pass $uid to the function if a session-variable is used
```

It should probably be:

```
$que->bindParam('uid', $uid);
```

Comment: ReapWhatYouSow is called when the player tries to use the item in question. and thank you for pointing out the $uid issue. still getting the issue, however.

Comment: Try adding colons to your bindParams... like $que->bindParam(':uid', $uid);